# How properly call an instance method and class method afterwards

Tags: ruby, class, instance

I would like to save some string in my database, but by using just one line without creating instance of the Object, like:

```
Secret.add('SuperSecret')
```

So I have the following class:

```
class Secret
  include MongoMapper::Document
  [some keys...]

def self.add(secret)
  if not secret.is_a? String
    return 'Not a string'
  end

  s = Secret.new(secret)
  s.save
end
```

But that doesnt look good...

Please don't tell me I can use MongoMapper validators, that's not the case here,
it's more about writing guidelines.

Thank you

Comment: Doubt you can, you can certainly neaten it up though. return 'Not a string' unless secret.is_a? String, followed by Secret.new(secret).save

Answer (score 1):

```
class SecretTypeError < StandardError; end

def self.add(secret)
  unless secret.is_a?(String)
    raise SecretTypeError, "Expected type String, got #{secret.class}"
  end

  self.new(secret).save
end
```

Raise an error instead of returning a string, or at least return `false` so you can test for it.  Alternatively use a string validator and alias your `add` method to `new`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `self.new` instead of `Secret.new`. And since the `add` method is a class method, the `self` can be skipped. Something like this would work:

```
class Secret
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :secret, String

  def self.add(secret_key)
    raise "Not a string" unless key.is_a?(String)

    s = new(secret: secret_key)
    s.save
  end
end
```